# Why is there a black hole in the Heatmap?

Tags: qgis, heat-map

After running the Heatmap tool in QGIS I like to color the geoTiff according to my wishes. Using Psuedo color works fine, but it leaves me with no options, as type of color scheme or transparancy on certain values, however chosing color-map instead of psuedo creates a black hole  hole right in the middle, where the intensity (heat) should be strongest.

Doesn't matter how I classify, 5, 10 or 20 classes...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Black holes like that are usually caused by raster values exceeding the range of the color ramp. Try adding another class with a higher associated value. That should fix it.

Comment: Looking at my metadata "tab" the highest value should be; quote: STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=70.522705078125 look at my new Pic, however i classified with a new class, but the hole remains...? http://picturepush.com/public/8864222

Comment: Seems like the statistics are wrong. There is no data missing, otherwise Pseudocolor wouldn't work fine.

Comment: I didn't get that. How is it wrong? Its just X and Y data interpolated, what can be wrong?

Comment: My point was that the STATISTICS_MAXIMUM value seems to be wrongly calculated.#